# Trying to create a cart Counter Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a counter variable where when a user clicks "Add To Cart" a number will appear indicating that the item was added and the number shown represents how many items are in the cart. My AddToCart controller can create a list and set it to a session variable. But I am having trouble setting the session variable without having to refresh the page. I believe it has something to do with my ajax. My main problem is that I don't know how to be able to access the new session variable so that the number next to the cart button updates when the add to cart button is pressed.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddToCart(int ProductID)
        {
            
            Products productAccess = new Products();
            List<ProductTier> HomeList = productAccess.IndexList();


            CartAccess cartaccess = new CartAccess();

            Cart product = cartaccess.FindProduct(ProductID);
            product.Quantity = 1;

            
            if (Session["cart"] == null)
            {
                List<Cart> ProductList = new List<Cart>();
                ProductList.Add ( product );
                Session["cart"] = ProductList;
                Session["CartCounter"] = ProductList.Count;
            }

            else
            {
                List<Cart> Existingcart = (List<Cart>)Session["cart"];
                int index = isExist(ProductID);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Existingcart[index].Quantity++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Existingcart.Add(product);
                }
                Session["cart"] = Existingcart;
                Session["CartCounter"] = Existingcart.Count;
            }

            return Json("Success");

        }
```

```
function AddToCart(item) {
        var ProductID = $(item).attr("ProductID");
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ProductID", ProductID);

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: '/Default/AddToCart',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.sucess) {
                    $("#CartItem").text("Sucess Working : " + data);
                    window.alert("Success");
                    alert('Success Work');
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            }
            
        });
        
        

    }
```

```
<div style="text-align:right;width:30%;margin-right:10px">
                        <input type="button" name="AddToCart" value="Add To Cart" class="btn btn-info" ProductID="@item.ProductID" onclick="AddToCart(this)">
                    </div>


<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ml-auto" style="margin-left:auto;">

                @if (Session["CartCounter"] == null)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cart", "Checkout", "DefaultController", new { @class = "nav-link", id = "CartItem" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cart(" + Session["CartCounter"] + ")", "Checkout", "DefaultController", new { @class = "nav-link" , id = "CartItem" })
                }
            </li>

        </ul>
```

I am still new to MVC and am learning new methods, Please give me any tips I would appreciate it.

Comment: Return more than the message "success", send the value you pulled from the Session store.

Comment: I added this to the end of the AddToCart Controller
`return Json(Session["CartCounter"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: The thing about ajax requests is that it won't reload or re-render the page automatically. Since, you've made an ajax post, the Session in the view code won't update because it had already taken the value and sent the page to the browser. Now, in the success handler, you need to read the returned value and update the appropriate  html elements.